# Exporting from Blender to Browser (Web Viewer)? What is the best way?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, versions, blend4web, webgl

Currently I have modeled 3D products in version 2.83 of Blender, using cycles as a rendering reference. And I have been using version 2.72 to create Web view pages (.html) of these objects, with the Blend4Web add-on, which was discontinued in version 2.72 of Blender. I was having satisfactory results when the product did not have very complex materials, as is the case with this object below:

Render Cycles (Blender 2.83):
[image]
[image]

Browser - (Blend4Web):

- http://www.gabrielmagalhaes.net.br/3dmodel/snack/
- http://www.gabrielmagalhaes.net.br/3dmodel/omo/

However, with products that have more complex materials, such as glass and metal, I have certain problems. As is the case with the following object:

Render Cycles (Blender 2.83):
[image]

Browser - (Blend4Web):
- http://www.gabrielmagalhaes.net.br/3dmodel/geleia/

In other words, I'm stuck in version 2.72 of Blender, just to create the 3D view pages. Also I am having big problems with material compatibility between cycles and B4W. That is my problem.

I need my products to be very detailed, the way I model them in cycles. With good reflexes, and very realistic.

What would be the best substitute to Blend4Web?

What do you suggest? Is there any other tool that helps me to create 3D visualization pages of my products, without having problems with the materials created in cycles ??

Answer (score 3):

The direct successor to Blend4Web would be Verge 3D: https://www.soft8soft.com/
This is in active development and should be quite good for what you want.

Alternatively, you could try out https://sketchfab.com/

If you want something FOSS, you might want to give Godot a try: https://www.godotengine.org/ It has  WebGL-export and the model and material transfer from Blender works rather well, but it may require somewhat more effort than the two abovementioned alternatives.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I hadn't tried Verge3D yet, but I will try it.
There are no problems if is FOSS or not. My superior gave me a generous budget, as long as I find a good tool to do that.

Do you think https://sketchfab.com/ can be even better than Keyshot?

We need really good realism in Browser.

Comment: To be honest, I can only speak from a hobbyist's point of view.
From my experience, I'd say that Verge3D will give you pretty good realism, maybe on a similar level with EEVEE, if you know what you are doing. Sketchfab seems to be pretty capable also, judging from what others achieve (see the respective posts at blendernation, for example). I don't know Keyshot at all.

Comment: @GabrielMagalhães Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: Actually, I would like to hear other people's opinions. And if possible from someone who has worked with Keyshot or Marmoset for web.

Comment: I might suggest https://modelviewer.dev/. Both it, and Godot, rely on glTF export from Blender 2.80+, which [supports many Principled BSDF material settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). There are some limits there (glass, particularly, is limited) that are being worked on.

Comment: @GabrielMagalhães Is there a quick, easy, and FREE way to translate or export to the web in Blender 3.4? (All of this 3D modelling is brand new to me.)

Comment: @haarigertroll The question above is directed at you too <3

Comment: Hi @oldboy!
What seems to be the problem with my original answer? Did you look at my suggestions?

Comment: @Don McCurdy I was able to create some experiences using model-viewer, after trying lots of stuffs, it gave me one of the best results, but is has lots of issues when it comes to iOS experiences. I know that it converts .glb files to .usdz automatically, and it runs ok when the model doesn't have animations. But in most of my cases my 3D models have animations and the model-viewer itself doesn't work good with that.
I wanted my AR applications to run on iOS too (animated 3D models), with no issues, what would you suggest me ? Any idea ?

Comment: @haarigertroll my aim is to create my own webpages, and not use someone's tools, or what we call third-part tools, what is the case of the Sketchfab. The old Blend4Web allowed me to embed it to my webpage, and run without any kind of watermark of fixed features, what is not possible with sketchfab too.

Does the verge3D allows me to do that? Other issues that I've seeing a lot is incompatibility with iOS devices. Mainly when talking about animated 3D models. Would you suggest something else?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf might do a better job generating the USDZ for you, and then you could use that pre-baked USDZ with model-viewer. Otherwise the options for getting content into iOS Quick Look are unfortunately very limited.